# Does ReactJS not work with Zurb Foundation Accordions?

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, reactjs

I'm trying to use React to create `ul` components that are supposed to be accordions.  I had it working before I was using React but when I use it, the foundation accordion is not working.  The accordion content just stays hidden when I click on them.

```
var pairingLi = React.createClass({
  return (
        <ul className='accordion submissionHolder no-bullet' data-accordian="">
            {
                this.props.data.map(function (pairingData) {
                    var id = "pairing_" + pairingData.pairingID;
                    var contentId = "content_" + pairingData.pairingID;
                    console.log(parseFloat(pairingData.pairingRate) * 100);
                    var fill = parseInt(parseFloat(pairingData.pairingRate) * 100);
                    var link = '#' + contentId;
                    return (
                        <li key={pairingData.pairingID} id={id} className='questionGroup accordion-navigation'>
                            <a href={link}>
                                <div className="back percentFill" data-value={fill} data-question-type="2"></div>
                                <div className="front">
                                    <i className="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down pull-right"></i>

                                    <div>{pairingData.itemName} to {pairingData.secondaryItemName}</div>
                                    <div>Pairing Success Rate: {pairingData.formattedRate}</div>
                                </div>
                            </a>

                            <div id={contentId} className="content">
                                <div className="surveyItem row">
                                    <div className="small-6 columns surveyItemLabel">
                                        Number of prompts:
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="small-6 columns surveyItemValue">
                                        {pairingData.pairingPrompts}
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="small-6 columns surveyItemLabel">
                                        Number of times user said yes to pairing prompt:
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="small-6 columns surveyItemValue">
                                        {pairingData.promptsYes}
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="small-6 columns surveyItemLabel">
                                        Number of times user said no to pairing prompt:
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="small-6 columns surveyItemValue">
                                        {pairingData.promptsNo}
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="small-6 columns surveyItemLabel">
                                        Total revenue generated from pairing:
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="small-6 columns surveyItemValue">
                                        {pairingData.formattedUpsale}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                    );
                })
                }
        </ul>
    );
});
```

I have lifecycle methods in there but everything is commented out.

Comment: can you provide the rest of the component code? Ultimately, you can probably build an accordion with very little effort using only react, and still use the zurb styles.  But if you want to use their plugin, you will have to jump through a few hoops to get it to play nice.

Comment: many of their components require jQuery activation. Are you doing that?

Comment: @DimitriKennedy what more would you like to see?  I'll post the whole component code.  What hoops must be jumped through?

Comment: @WiredPrairie I include a jQuery.min.js that comes with foundation.

Comment: Sure -- but Zurb's code has to actually "activate" the components. There's info on the web page for the accordion: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say exactly how to fix your problem without the rest of the component code, but I have wrapped a number of non-react internal tools that I use, using something close to the following:

```
    React.createClass
        displayName: "myPluginWrapper"

        componentDidMount: ->
            @$element = $( @getDomNode() )
            @renderPluginContent()

            @$element.plugin(@props.pluginOpts)

        renderPluginContent: (props) ->
          props = props or @props
          React.renderComponent(<div>{props.children}</div>, @$element[0])

        componentWillReceiveProps: (newProps)-> 
            #check for whatever options have changed or if u
            #are changing the elements that u are passing in here   

            if newProps.children isnt @props.children
              @renderPluginContent(newProps)

            if newProps.pluginOpts isnt @props.pluginOpts
              #if hte options have changed then do what u need to
              #to pass them back through
              @$element(newProps.pluginOpts)

        onClose: ->
          React.unmountComponentAtNode(@vex[0])

        render: ->
          <div />
```

## USAGE

```
      <myPluginWrapper pluginOpts={pluginOpts}>
        #all of your accordion markup
        <ul className="accordion-class">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul
      </myPluginWrapper>
```